# Java IO , loading and saving binary file

Tags: java, io

I have the following code, on method readAndWriteBinary, save the image correctly.
The second one loads to a List of Bytes, and then write to the file. But the image is broken...

You can use any image.

I am trying to find out what's wrong into the broken process but till now I didn't get what is it.

```
...
  import com.google.common.primitives.Bytes;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;
....
  private void readAndWriteBinary() throws IOException {
    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("IMAGE-TESTING.PNG");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("IMAGE-SINGLE.PNG")) {
      byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
      while (fis.read(bytes) > 0) {
        List<Byte> bytesAux = Bytes.asList(bytes);
        fos.write(Bytes.toArray(bytesAux), 0, bytesAux.size());
      }
    }
  }
  /*
  This scenario doesn't works, looks to be the same as the readAndWriteBinary one
   */
  private void readAndWriteBinaryNonWorking() throws IOException {
    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("IMAGE-TESTING.PNG");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("IMAGE-SINGLE.PNG")) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        List<List<Byte>> bytesAux = new ArrayList<>();
        while (fis.read(bytes) > 0) {
          bytesAux.add(Bytes.asList(bytes));
        }
        for(List<Byte> bytesTmp : bytesAux) {
          fos.write(Bytes.toArray(bytesTmp), 0, bytesTmp.size());
        }
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: I just figured out what make it work, but i still don't know why ...
Just replace the line :  List<List<Byte>> bytesAux = ArrayList<>();  with List<List<Byte> bytesAux = LinkedList<>();

Comment: You are discarding the value returned by `fis.read(bytes)`.  As [the documentation points out](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)), that return value is important.  Also, converting your byte arrays to and from `List<Byte>` is very inefficient and serves no purpose;  just use byte arrays and don’t use Lists.

Comment: ok but using a primitive byte Array , doesnt help into dealing with a variable size of list.
I will have to manually deal with that ? Isnt what the List does anyway ?

About the read, the documentation its says about the return of the read:
"the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the file has been reached." 

since I'm using the read bytes, and its a array already filled, the only drawback that i see here is when the size readed isn't the same as the number of bytes 1024.

Comment: “…its a array already filled” —It is *not* guaranteed to be filled.  That’s why you need to save the value returned from `read`.  You should not be trying to read the entire file contents and then write the entire file contents.  Just call `read`, then write out whatever bytes were obtained.

Comment: i fixed this behavior on the answer below, but before getting to it, i tried a version getting the size into entries to the List of the array, so it got entries of 1024 till the last read of something smaller, creating a array of bytes with same size till the end but It didnt work. Only  when i set a single one as the result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I gave up of putting into a list of list of arrays , and the working solution become a single array written in one time. I didn't like much about its because the memory consumption , but for my case its a small one anyway.  May be a bufferedWriter could deal better with that

Remarks that the type of collection doesn't means anything..

```
  private void readAndWriteBinaryNonWorking() throws IOException {
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("DGII.PNG");
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("DGII-SINGLE.PNG")) {
      byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
      List<Byte> bytesAux = new LinkedList<>();
      int size;
      do  {
        size = fis.read(bytes);
        bytesAux.addAll(Bytes.asList(bytes));
      } while ((size) > 0) ;
      fos.write(Bytes.toArray(bytesAux), 0, bytesAux.size());
    }
  }
```

Comment: i am wondering why this answer is bad , since the concept I'm trying to work on is the using of the List itself. If theres a better answer, be welcome to provide it .

Comment: I repeat what I said above:  `fis.read(bytes)` is *not guaranteed to fill the byte array.*  So writing all of the bytes in that array is incorrect behavior.

Comment: you said it wont fill the byte array, ok thats understood. What it fills is returned into the size variable ? isn't it ?   so i will have a array with a size that is variable , but only into the last read. I am wrong?

Comment: There is no such thing as an array with a size that is variable.  You declared `bytes` with a length of 1024, so it will always have a length of 1024.  And `Bytes.asList` always adds 1024 bytes, regardless of the value of `size`.

Answer (score 0):

In fail case You create multidimensional array List<List> and `readAndWriteBinaryNonWorking` filled list some like this:

```
[
[0],
[0],
[0],
[0],
[0]
]
```

In success case You filled list as expected (byte array format):

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

ArrayList vs LinkedList in you case is no difference, because finally you converted him to byte array.

Comment: this conclusing of changing the king of List, was weird for me, so i have my doubts about  indeed.
And my be i got a image that fit well for some reason and worked. But weirdly it worked only with linkedlist.

having a list of list, is what i was expecting anyway, since i will execute the groups of bytes 1024 and write.  What is missing from my eyes is what is wrong from one to another, since the write just get a byte array of 1024 , and push to the write function.